# Catboost: Categorcial Feature Encoding

Tags: encoding, catboost

I would like to understand all the methods available in Catboost for
encoding categorical features.

Unfortunately, the published articles by Yandex
(["CatBoost: gradient boosting with categorical features support"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.11363) and ["CatBoost: unbiased boosting with categorical features"](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2018/file/14491b756b3a51daac41c24863285549-Paper.pdf))
do not go into much detail on this regard.

The [official documentation](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic)
and a tutorial on their [Github](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/master/catboost/tutorials/categorical_features/categorical_features_parameters.ipynb)
provide some clues, but I still have some questions:

1. Do all methods require the conversion of labels to integers ([stage 2](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic))?

   - It is not clear to me whether **Float Target Mean Value** actually uses these discretised labels.
2. For the methods **Buckets** and **Borders**, does one apply another quantisation on top of [stage 2](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic)?

   - It seems to me that they could be directly applied to targets in a regression task – without the need of stage 2.
3. What is the difference between `CtrBorderType` and `TargetBorderType`? The documentation says the former is the "quantization type of the label value" while the latter is for categorical features. When do you need to apply quantization on categorical features?

   - EDIT: I seem to have found an answer to this. According to their [Github](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/master/catboost/tutorials/categorical_features/categorical_features_parameters.ipynb) (see section "Default value of simple_ctr and combinations_ctr"), `CtrBorderType` can be used to discretize encoded categorical values.
4. How are categorical features encoded during inference?

   - I suspect the latest encoded occurrence of each category (in the shuffled dataset) is used in each tree. However, I can't find anything to substantiate this hypothesis.